# Boy accidentally travels back in time with a device meant to allow people to view the past without being there

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I think this was a kids book about a boy who travelled back in time accidentally via a device that used to let people view events from the past but without being there.

- There was a company who designed it in the future. Might have been around the year 3000, and this kid won a contest and got to use the new device.
- One event was the killing of the last whale, another was the Big Bang and there were a few others like when life first walked on Earth from the sea.
- He landed in some kid's closet maybe?

It was a great book.

Comment: Can you tell us when you read this? What language/country? Was it a short story or a novel?

Answer (score 5):

You're referring to "[Rule #1: Don't Touch Anything](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0689868774)", part of the [TimeJumpers](http://www.goodreads.com/series/76274-timejumpers) series of books by James Valentine.

> The first and only rule of time travel in the year fifteen billion and
>   seventy-three is simple enough: DON'T TOUCH ANYTHING. Theodore Pine
>   Four is perfectly willing to follow this rule **when he wins a contest
>   for the latest TimeMaster JumpMan.** If all goes according to plan, this
>   new model should send him -- as an invisible onlooker -- to an
>   exciting time and place for a five-minute test-run. But instead of
>   landing somewhere cool, like the fall of Troy or the sinking of the
>   Titanic, **why does he end up in the middle of some girl's bedroo**m in
>   the twenty-first century, where nothing interesting is happening?

Farah offers some additional info in her review [here](http://farah-sf.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/time-on-our-hands-james-valentine.html):

> Jules and Gen, two teens, are the in the room in which Theo
>   materialises, and who need to keep him occupied at the same time as
>   they sort out their own problems. While Theo works out how to get the
>   co-ordinates to go home, they jump with him to different times,
>   including the First Fish, and **the Last Whale**. Eventually, when Theo
>   falls sick, Jules jumps forward to bring back his parents.

[image]